# Use google docs as an editor and viewer

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

I am looking to use google docs editor and viewers for docs , sheets etc in my application.

i.e. the files are hosted in my application and just want to open the office files in the google docs UIs. So , just want to use google docs UIs not the google docs as a server.

As per the below [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59253838/can-use-google-docs-as-editor-for-my-application) it is not possible.

But was just wondering how [BOX](https://support.box.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043696994-Introducing-Box-for-G-Suite) has achieved the same.

MS Office online supports the same use case through [WOPI](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). So was looking for something similar for google docs.

Comment: "Knowing that, what you can do is to synchronize both storage sides, synchronize only the working folders with Drive API, etc."....

Comment: Yes, but this means maintaining a storage on google drive as well